# PHP if foreach show ads every 5 loop

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php 
$args = array('posts_per_page'=> 100,'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) :

    if($i == 5){
        $i ==1; 
        xxxxx
    }else{
        $i++;
    }
    ?>       
    <div class="thumbBlock" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        123
    </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

xxxxx is my ads. 
yes is duplicated

but not working help my please

Comment: What does it mean **not working**? You have errors? Unexpected output? Or we should guess by ourselves?

Comment: What is exactly the problem? 
Note in your <div> the id will always be "post-". If you intend to have something like id="post-01234" then you should add "echo"

Comment: Your example never shows you defining, and initializing $i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `$i` is divisible by 5 if so you can show your ads

```
<?php 
$args = array('posts_per_page'=> 100,'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
$i = 0;
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) :
    if ($i % 5 == 0) {
        # code to show your ads
    }else{
        #show something else
    }
    $i++;
    ?>       
    <div class="thumbBlock" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        123
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not resetting the counter properly. Change the `$i == 1` to `$i = 1`. Also make sure that `$i` is correctly initialized.

```
<?php $args = array('posts_per_page'=> 100,'orderby' => 'rand' );
$rand_posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $rand_posts as $post ) :  
    if($i == 5){
        $i = 1;  // <--- reset, don't test for $i == 1 
        xxxxx
    }else{i++;}?>       
<div class="thumbBlock" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
123
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: No, `the_ID()` is one of those Wordpress functions that already echo by themselves [WP Docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID)